# Trying to recognize Fn + V on my keyboard

Tags: autohotkey

I hate that when I'm using my laptop on its own I often type FN+v when I mean to paste. So I decided to solve my problem with AHK. I installed a keyboard hook in my main script,and used that to extract the fn keys value, 163. My initial test worked, but adding the & to make it a modifier does not. What am I overlooking?

So this doesn't work

```
SC163 & v:: 
MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed.
return
```

but this did work

```
SC163:: 
MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed.
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the FN key, it might be remapping the "v" to something else (like "Media_Play_Pause" button) in the keyboard driver. Therefore the key code wouldn't be `SC163  & v` but something like `SC159`.

The [Special Keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) section for mentions a method to get the Scan code:

1. Ensure that at least one script is running that is using the keyboard hook. You can tell if a script has the keyboard hook by opening its main window and selecting "View->Key history" from the menu bar.
2. Double-click that script's tray icon to open its main window.
3. Press one of the "mystery keys" on your keyboard.
4. Select the menu item "View->Key history"
5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Somewhere near the bottom are the key-down and key-up events for your key. **NOTE: Some keys do not generate events and thus will not be visible here. If this is the case, you cannot directly make that particular key a hotkey because your keyboard driver or hardware handles it at a level too low for AutoHotkey to access.** For possible solutions, see [Special Keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).
6. If your key is detectable, make a note of the 3-digit hexadecimal value in the second column of the list (e.g. 159).

Comment: It appears that it is just ignoring all non-function key input while the fn key is held down.